# add another backround image to an element on hover, when the current image has been assigned by ID?

Tags: html, css

You know you can have multiple background images on a single element in CSS3?

```css
background-image: url(image.png) , url(image1.png);
```

I need to append another image URL without replacing the current one, on the 'hover' event.

I've tried:

```css
element:hover
{    
    background-image: url(image1.png);    
}
```

With no luck.

However, If I simply just re-assign all images in the hover event, all works well:

```css
element:hover
{    
    background-image: url(image.png) , url(image1.png);    
}
```

But I can't do that because I'm using `id`'s to assign the primary image, which differ from id to id. So something like this:

```css
.buttonClass
{    
/*width and height stuff here*/    
}

.buttonClass:hover
{    
/*this is where I add my ADDITIONAL image*/    
}

#buttonONE
{    
/*this is where I assign my primary image*/    
}

#buttonTWO
{    
/*this is where I assign my primary image from buttonTWO
  which is different from the image assigned to buttonONE*/    
}
```

SO the `id`'s will have the primary image, as they differ from id to id. So I could just do:

```css
#buttonOne:hover
{
/*but, the hover image (the additional image) I want to append will 
  not differ at all. It will always be the same.*/
    background-image: url(image.png) , url(image1.png);    
}

#buttonTwo:hover
{
/*so this method is pretty messy and pointless, 
  unless of course, it's the only way?*/
    background-image: url(imagedsfsdf.png) , url(image1.png);    
}
```

So I don't want to be throwing unnecessary hovers all over the place when I can just add it to the class hover, right?

So, any ideas?

Oh and one more thing - I would prefer to keep JS and jQuery out of it. Unless there's no other way...

Answer (score 0):

Mkae a fiddle or dabblet  then we all can help better

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/UaApb/

the size differences are only to illustrate what's going on, 50-75-100

Comment: That replaces the current image though. I need the current image to still be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be logical to use more than one HTML element?
For example, parent images stay intact, while child element images change when you hover over their parents.

Your CSS would be much cleaner

Comment: no because each ID will be assigned to a different 'parent' image. So I'll end up having hovers on id's all over the place.

Comment: You can do something like #parent:hover .child {background-image: url(something.jpg)}

Comment: Will I have to do that for each ID?

Comment: Do your hovered images differ from one element to another? if yes, you probably have no choice but to assign different image for each ID. if no, you can give them common class name such as .button instead of #button1, #button2, #button3